# Azure Data Factory: Dynamic path value for the Storage Event Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created an azure data factory pipeline to copy the data from one adls container to another adls container using copy data activity.
This copy activity will trigger using a storage event trigger.

So whenever a new file gets generated, it will trigger the activity.
The source file is located in a nested directory structure having dynamic folders such as year, month, and day, which vary based on date.

In the trigger, I mentioned the path until the fixed folder path, but I don't know what value I should put for the dynamic path.
Initially, I provided the path such as `my/fixed/directory/*/*/*/`,
but at the time of execution, it throws the exception 'PathNotFound'.

So my question is - How can I provide the path to the storage event trigger with the dynamic folder structure?
Following is ADF copy data pipeline screenshot:
**Pipeline-**
[image]

**Copy data activity source configuration-**
[image]

**Copy data activity target configuration-**
[image]

**Copy data activity source dataset configuration-**
[image]

**Copy data activity target dataset configuration-**
[image]

**Storage event configuration-**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Wildcards are not supported for `blob path begins with` or `blob path ends with` in storage event triggers.
- However, creating a storage event trigger on the fixed parent directory would trigger the pipeline for any file created/deleted in child directories as well.
- Let's say I have the folder structure as shown below where `input/folder/2022` is my fixed directory (input is container name). I also have sub folders within each of the folders shown below.

[image]

- Now, I have created a copy data activity. The folder name and file name dynamic content for source dataset is shown below (parameter values will be passed from pipeline):

```
folder path:  @replace(dataset().folder_name,'input/','')

file name:  @dataset().file_name
```

[image]

- The folder name and file name dynamic content for sink dataset is shown below. This is a different container named `data`:

```
folder path: @concat('output/',replace(dataset().folder,'input/folder/',''))

file name: @dataset().file
```

[image]

- After configuring the copy activity is done, create a storage event trigger.

[image]

- Here, the values from pipeline parameters `folderName` and `fileName` will be set while creating trigger as shown below:

```
fileName : @triggerBody().fileName
folderName : @triggerBody().folderPath
```

[image]

- After you attach the trigger and create a pipeline, when ever any file is uploaded to any folder within the fixed directory `folder/2022` the pipeline will be triggered.
- I have uploaded a file to `folder/2022/03/01/sample1.csv`. This triggered the pipeline successfully.

[image]

- The file is successfully copied as well. The following is an image for reference:

[image]

So, creating a storage event trigger for just the parent directory is sufficient to be able to trigger the pipeline for any file uploaded to child directories as well.

Comment: Hi @Saideep I have done almost the same thing but still my pipeline failed to get the file.  Can we pass the `@concat('RAW/SYSTEM/CaseDetails/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'dd'))` dynamic value to the `Blob path begins with` ?

Comment: Hey @venus, I dont think dynamic content can be used for blob path begins with. Can you edit the question to include the complete error message? and the file path you have given for both source and sink in the copy activity.

Comment: Hi @Saideep I have added the screenshot of the pipeline.

Comment: Can you make these changes as indicated in these images for [source dataset](https://i.imgur.com/cnTKol7.png) and [sink dataset](https://i.imgur.com/WCGsVy3.png) and try again.

Comment: Hey @venus, did the pipeline trigger as per requirement? Provide the error message in case it failed again.

Comment: Hi @Saideep- I could not deploy the pipeline. I'll let you know by monday. Thank you so much for your kind help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey @venus, provide additional details in case the pipeline did not trigger as per requirement.

Comment: Hi @Saideep I'm indebted with your kind help. at present I have deprioritized this approach. for my current ingestion task. probably after few days will test it.